# onepage checkout page only order total without order total incl tax

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

In my web when I use theme luma, order total incl.Tax can been see in checkout.But if I change to my theme x, it only have order total without order total incl tax .So what should I do for my theme to display like luma with order total incl. Tax.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In theme checkout_index_index.xml .
The components loading in the sidebar were that of Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total instead of Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total.
Change file ,loading in the sidebar with  Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total can display Order Total Incl. Tax.